# Plugin Store doesn't get content

Tags: plugins

Craft 3 RC is installed locally. After clicking on the **Plugin Store** the loading animation stays for 1-3 seconds. After that, the right canvas leaves grey without content.

- I've checked the XHR request, it seems working.
- reinstalled Craft with composer
- tested several browsers

What could be a reason for an empty Plugin Store?

---

**Update**

I've tested the issue with a clean install of Craft 3, same problem there. So it should be something global on my machine.

Someone have an idea where the problem could be hidden?

Comment: Have you tried emptying/deleting your `storage` folder?

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff Yes, no success…

Comment: @BradBell No, unfortunately not.

Comment: The plugin store in the Control Panel is actually a Vue.js app.  Maybe you've got something else loaded (rewrites, plugins, etc.) loaded interfering with it's routing?

Comment: @BradBell yes, I had an old contact form in the plugins folder. I've emptied it without any changes afterward. Where should the Vue.js be?

Comment: @BradBell May you missed my answer? :x

Comment: Craft ships it in `src/web/assets/pluginsstore`, but it will get published to the public HTML folder of your site into a random folder name.  Was thinking more along the lines if you had another Vue app running or some htaccess rewrite rules that might be interfering with Craft loading its Vue app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Craft update solved the issue! Now finally I can see the content of the Plugin Store.

Answer (score 4):

I had to download the CA certificate for curl :

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

And added it to php.ini to get the plugin store working on my local dev env.

curl.cainfo = "x:\path\cacert.pem"

[IIS windows as local dev env]